# Adjust the RMarkdown HTML output to maximize on page load

Tags: r, r-markdown

Is there any way to adjust the RMarkdown HTML output to maximize to the full window size on page load?

Comment: what do you mean with full window size?

Comment: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#appearance-and-style you can add a custom .css to adapt the appearance. But you can only do, what would be possible to adapt web pages with .css. So you can't force the browser itself to suddenly go full screen if you meant this.